# Concatenate string in with open() as line

Tags: python

How to concatenate the reading line of the `open()` module, a new string with its delimiter?

**Script:**

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    file = file + "@" + newString
    resultSplit.append([line.split('@') for line in file])
```

**Output:**

```
[FAILED] Caused by: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'str', will be treated later.
```

**Desired output:**

```
[['DataExample1','DataExample2','NewString']]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you expect `file + "@" + newString` to do.

Comment: `file` and the `file.txt` reading line, I would just like to add a new string to the end of that line with `@` at the beginning

Comment: `file = file.read() + "@" + newString`

Comment: thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file` is not a string and, therefore, you can't append a string to it.  What you could do is the following

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    resultSplit.append([(line+'@'+newString).split('@') for line in file])
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was not understanding how to do, thanks!